# Organ secretions

Tags: gene-expression, anatomy, gene, general-biology, animal-models

If an animal secrets an enzyme from an organ that is entirely dedicated for the same secretion, can one or cannot one just use the gene coding for that protein to obtain the protein in vitro. How much relevance does the organ have for production of a particular enzyme. For example, hippopotamus releases the blood sweat from glands in its fat skin. Can one use just the gene coding for the blood sweat and produce it in vitro, or the organ is necessary for it's production?

Comment: That is a complicated question that ends up with the answer of, it depends. Most Eukaryotic proteins require chaperone proteins to fold correctly. Many proteins also undergo post-translational modifications, especially those produced in the ER for secretion of presentation on the cell surface. That being said, pharmaceutical human insulin and growth factors are produced by bacteria. Also it is the cell that is relevant, the organ is just the conglomeration of cells of a certain differentiation type. Those cells will express their genes based on how they differentiated.

Comment: Also, blood sweat sounds like it results from two compounds, and are small acidic molecules. If you were to isolate the enzyme(s) that produced them and added them to their substrate, then they should catalyze the reaction to produce the molecules, assuming that there are not other cofactors necessary that you have not added to the reaction.

Comment: It's not a product of two compounds.....it is called blood sweat as it is red in colour and is released as sweat from the skin

Comment: "The secretion is sometimes referred to as "blood sweat", but is neither blood nor sweat. This secretion is initially colourless and turns red-orange within minutes, eventually becoming brown. Two distinct pigments have been identified in the secretions, one red (hipposudoric acid) and one orange (norhipposudoric acid). The two pigments are highly acidic compounds." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamus#Description